# "Finishing" a for loop in Python

Tags: python

I am new to object oriented from Bash.  I have a very simple question that I having difficulty phrasing in Google or here on Stack Overflow.

How do I indicate the end of a for loop?  The examples I have seen do not have a "Done" (from what I am used to in Bash).  How would I run through this code until the last character is output? How do I then add more code without the program being included in the for loop?

```
for i in ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']:
    print i
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply don't indent the code you want to be outside of your loop. Python is white-space sensitive.

```
for i in ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']:
    print i

# The code at this indentation is not part of the above block.
print 42
```

Comment: With the addendum that continue and break statements can be used to skip an element that is being looped over or exit the loop if necessary.